# Lineendings changed by git

Tags: git, github

I'm working on Win10 with the GitHub desktop tool and grunt.

Somehow my Apple-using boss decided to implement lineending restrictions to our style-checker only allowing unix-lineendings.

Everytime I pull some of our files seem to be rewritten by git or something which results in the stylechecker blaming me for using \r\n lineending instead of \n

I already set unix-lineendings as default for every file in Sublime Text 2 and also tried this: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

But the problem is still present. Any idea what setting I need to change and where to find it?

Comment: look for "core.autocrlf"

Comment: Some IDEs convert line endings every time you save a file. Could also be a setting with your editor. But agree with the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

You weren't clear with what you tried from that article. If you set `core.autocrlf` to `true`, then Git will replace all `\n`s with `\r\n`. It's what you want if you use Windows-based tools that can't recognize a `\n` by itself, but not what it sounds like you want in this case.

It sounds like what you want is:

`git config --global core.autocrlf input`

Which will convert all `\r\n` to `\n` when you check them in (i.e., "input" them) and do nothing when you check them out. All files then should have just `\n`.